# Getting Warning: rule cannot be matched

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

So i am trying to make e lexical parsher using Flex Code with a bit of Bison.I keep getting a warning about my rules than cannot be matched and i cannot find any error.I have also searched what that warning means,but i think i haven't declared a similar rule again.So there is no chance i think that any other rule overpasses other rules and cannot be matched.I keep getting an error from line 83 which is {COMMA}    {return COMMA;},till the end of my code and i dunno why.Any ideas?

```
WHITESPACE   [ \t]
INTDEC   [0]|([1-9][0-9]*)
INTHEX   0[xX][0-9A-F]+
INTOCTAL   0[0-7]+
VARIABLE   [A-Za-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]+
COMMA   ","
INT   "int"
FLOAT   "float"
DOUBLE   "double"
VOID   "void"
LONG   "long"
SHORT   "short"
BREAK   "break"
RETURN   "return"
LEKTIKA   \"(\\[n"\\]|[^"\\\n])*\"
COMMENTS   "//".*
REAL   ([0][.][0-9]+)|([1-9][0-9]*[.][0-9]+)
EXP   ([0-9]+|{REAL})[Ee]-?[0-9]+
UNKNOWN_TOKEN   [^ \t\n]*
NEWLINE   \n
LESS_THAN   [<]
GREATER_THAN   [>]
GREATER_OR_EQUAL_TO   [>\=]
LESS_OR_EQUAL_TO   [<\=]
NOT_EQUAL_TO   [\=!]
EQUAL   [\=\=]
DIVIDE   [\/]
MULTIPLY   [\*]
MODULO   [%]
PLUS   [\+]
MINUS   [\-]
PLUS_ASSIGN   [\+\=]
MINUS_ASSIGN   [\-\=]
MULT_ASSIGN   [\*\=]
DIV_ASSIGN   [\/\=]
LOGICAL_AND   [&&]
LOGICAL_OR   [\|\|]
INCREMENT   [\+\+]
DECREMENT   [\-\-]
ALL_OPERATORS   [{LESS_THAN}{GREATER_THAN}{GREATER_OR_EQUAL_TO}{LESS_OR_EQUAL_TO}{NOT_EQUAL_TO}{EQUAL}{DIVIDE}{MULTIPLY}{MODULO}{PLUS}{MINUS}{PLUS_ASSIGN}{MINUS_ASSIGN}{MULT_ASSIGN}{DIV_ASSIGN}   {LOGICAL_AND}{LOGICAL_OR}{INCREMENT}{DECREMENT}]
SCAN   scan[[(][{VARIABLE}][)];
LEN   len[(][{VARIABLE}|{LEKTIKA}|{INTDEC}|{REAL}|{EXP}]*[)];
CMP   cmp[(][{VARIABLE}|{LEKTIKA}|{INTDEC}|{REAL}|{EXP},]*[)];
PRINT   print[(][{VARIABLE}|{LEKTIKA}|{INTDEC}|{REAL}|{EXP}]*[)];
FUNCTION_NAME   {VARIABLE}
FUNCTION   [func]+\s[{FUNCTION_NAME}]+\s[(]+[{INT}|{FLOAT}|{DOUBLE}\s+[{VARIABLE}],\s]*[)]
CALL_FUNC   [{FUNCTION_NAME}][(][{INTEDEC}|{INTHEX}|{INOCTAL}|{REAL}][)];
ARRAY_NAME   [{VARIABLE}]
ARRAY_CON   [\[][{INTDEC}|{VARIABLE}|{VARIABLE}|{LEKTIKA},\s]*
ARRAY   [{ARRAY_NAME}]\s[\=]\s[\[][{INTDEC}|{VARIABLE}|{VARIABLE}|{LEKTIKA},]*[\]];
DEC_INT   {INT}[{VARIABLE}];
DEC_FLOAT   {FLOAT}[{VARIABLE}];
DEC_DOUBLE   {DOUBLE}[{VARIABLE}];
COMPARISONS   [{VARIABLE}]\s[{LESS_THAN}|{GREATER_THAN}|{GREATER_OR_EQUAL_TO}|        {LESS_OR_EQUAL_TO}|{NOT_EQUAL_TO}|{EQUAL}]\s[{VARIABLE}]
DEC_VAR   [{DEC_INT}|{DEC_FLOAT}|{DEC_DOUBLE}];
VAR_ASSIGN   [{VARIABLE}|{ARRAY_NAME},\s]*\s[\=]\s[{INT}|{FLOAT}|{DOUBLE}|{ARRAY_CON},\s]*;



%%
{WHITESPACE}    {}
{COMMENTS}      {}
{INTDEC}        {return INTDEC;}
{INTHEX}        {return INTHEX;}
{INTOCTAL}      {return INTOCTAL;}
{REAL}          {return REAL;}
{EXP}           {return EXP;}
{LEKTIKA}       {return LEKTIKA;}
{VARIABLE}      {return VARIABLE;}
{NEWLINE}       {return NEWLINE;}
{UNKNOWN_TOKEN} {return UNKNOWN_TOKEN;}
{COMMA}    {return COMMA;}
{INT}    {return INT;}
{FLOAT}    {return FLOAT;}
{DOUBLE}    {return DOUBLE;}
{VOID}    {return VOID;}
{LONG}    {return LONG;}
{SHORT}    {return SHORT;}
{BREAK}    {return BREAK;}
{RETURN}    {return RETURN;}
{LESS_THAN}    {return LESS_THAN;}
{GREATER_THAN}    {return GREATER_THAN;}
{GREATER_OR_EQUAL_TO}    {return GREATER_OR_EQUAL_TO;}
{LESS_OR_EQUAL_TO}    {return LESS_OR_EQUAL_TO;}
{NOT_EQUAL_TO}    {return NOT_EQUAL_TO;}
{EQUAL}    {return EQUAL;}
{DIVIDE}    {return DIVIDE;}
{MULTIPLY}    {return MULTIPLY;}
{MODULO}    {return MODULO;}
{PLUS}    {return PLUS;}
{MINUS}    {return MINUS;}
{PLUS_ASSIGN}    {return PLUS_ASSIGN;}
{MINUS_ASSIGN}    {return MINUS_ASSIGN;}
{MULT_ASSIGN}    {return MULT_ASSIGN;}
{DIV_ASSIGN}    {return DIV_ASSIGN;}
{LOGICAL_AND}    {return LOGICAL_AND;}
{LOGICAL_OR}    {return LOGICAL_OR;}
{INCREMENT}    {return INCREMENT;}
{DECREMENT}    {return DECREMENT;}
{ALL_OPERATORS}    {return ALL_OPERATORS;}
{SCAN}    {return SCAN;}
{LEN}    {return LEN;}
{CMP}    {return CMP;}
{PRINT}    {return PRINT;}
{FUNCTION_NAME}    {return FUNCTION_NAME;}
{FUNCTION}    {return FUNCTION;}
{CALL_FUNC}    {return CALL_FUNC;}
{ARRAY_NAME}    {return ARRAY_NAME;}
{ARRAY_CON}    {return ARRAY_CON;}
{ARRAY}    {return ARRAY;}
{DEC_INT}    {return DEC_INT;}
{DEC_FLOAT}    {return DEC_FLOAT;}
{DEC_DOUBLE}    {return DEC_DOUBLE;}
{COMPARISONS}    {return COMPARISONS;}
{DEC_VAR}    {return DEC_VAR;}
{VAR_ASSIGN}    {return VAR_ASSIGN;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your rules, `{UNKNOWN_TOKEN}` appears very early. Since it matches any token of any length not containing whitespace, it will match the same tokens as any following rule (and possibly more characters as well). Since (f)lex always choses the first rule if more than one rule is possible, none of the rules after `{UNKNOWN_TOKEN}` will ever match.

I suggest you use fewer macros. (Or no macros at all.) They are not contributing anything to your code. They only make it unnecessarily long, and they are confusing you (I think) because macro definitions are not rules and the order of macro definitions does not affect the match, only the order of the rules themselves.

There are some other errors as well. For example, `[\+\+]` does not match `++`. It is a character class, so it matches precisely one character. The only character it can match is `+` because repeated characters in a set don't change the set. (There is no need to backslash-escape `+` in a character class either. Inside brackets most characters lose their special meaning.) What you meant was `"++"`.

Comment: I tried completely removing {UNKWNOWN TOKEN} but i keep receiving the same warnings.And what do you mean by saying "macros"?Do you mean the regular expressions?

Comment: @Kourkounatos: you will also have to fix the other errors. As I said, `[\+\+]` matches a single `+`, the same as `[\+]`. So you have two rules which match `+` and no rule which matches `++`. That's just an example; you'll have to fix a lot of rules. Note also that macros are not expanded inside character class brackets. `[{VARIABLE}]` matches a single character; it is *exactly* the same as `[{}ABEILRV]`.

Comment: @Kourkounatos: the lines before `%%` are macro definitions. `{name}` expands to the definition of `name`, but only in a context where `{}` are recognised as special. So `"{name}"`, `\{name}` and `[{name}]` are not macro expansions.

Comment: Lots of your rules use character classes incorrectly. Please reread the [documentation for patterns](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns). Also, start with a few rules and get that working. Then add more. Many of your rules shouldn't be there at all; they belong in a parser, not a lexical analyser.

Comment: Actually i am building a parser.Sorry for my mistake.Okay,i will fix these errors and i will let you know what happened